# Media Foundation: another way to call IMFActivate::ShutdownObject?

Tags: com, directshow, ms-media-foundation

Here is a question about `IMFActivate::ActivateObject` and `IMFActivate::ShutdownObject` in Media Foundation.

According to MSDN, the component that calls `ActivateObject` is responsible for calling `ShutdownObject`.

But there are two examples not following this rule:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388503%28VS.85%29.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317912%28VS.85%29.aspx

In these two examples, they call `ActivateObject` and then release `IMFActivate` interface without calling `ShutdownObject` method.

This is going to lead to memory leaking, right? Or there is another way to release the resource occupied by the object?

(Can I use `IMFMediaSource::Shutdown` to release the object instead of using `IMFActivate::ShutdownObject`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you're supposed to call `IMFActivate::ShutdownObject` when you're done using the object you activated.  However, notice that the sample in question is instantiating an IMFMediaSource to be returned in an out param.

```
HRESULT CreateVideoDeviceSource(IMFMediaSource **ppSource)
```

If CreateVideoDeviceSource were to do a ShutdownObject on the IMFMediaSource it instantiated and then hand it back to you, it would be in a shut-down state and therefore probably unusable.

To answer your question about what you're supposed to do about this, you can probably get away with a `pMyMediaSource->Shutdown()` after you're all done using it.

More info: IMFActivate's other use in Media Foundation is for allowing an MF object to be instantiated in a different process (useful because the MF Media Session will play DRM-protected content in a separate process); in that case, the MF Media Session will indeed call `IMFActivate::ShutdownObject` on any IMFActivates you gave it.